# Getting input in c with read()

Tags: c, input

So I am trying to take the users input using read(). The while loop runs until ctrl+d is entered in linux terminal and the input is stopped. I wrote some code and it works, but the problem I am running into is that I don't know how to take exactly whats in the input and how to use it.

In the code below, right after `if(buff[offset] == '\n')` (runs the given input, and after its finished clears the buffer and moves on to the next input) I don't know how to go into the 3 possible cases of input and also I don't know how to get the number from the second case:

- "e" - exit the program
- "p N" - do something, N is a number which I also need to get into a variable (I think that `buff[offset-1]` should get the number but I am not quite sure.)
- everything else - print a message

Code:

```
int fd = 0; // set read() to read from STDIN_FILENO, because it's number is 0
const size_t read_size = 1; // set chunk size
size_t size = read_size; 
size_t offset = 0;
size_t res = 0;

char *buff = malloc(size+1);
*buff = '\0';

while((res = read(fd, buff + offset, read_size)) > 0) // read from stdin and save to buff
{       
    if(buff[offset] == '\n')
    { // THIS PART
        buff[offset] = '\0';
        if(buff == "e")
        {
            // exit the program
            return 0;
        }
        else if(buff == "p")
        {
            // do sth
        }
        else
        {
            // print a message
        }
        
        // reset the buffer (free its memory and allocate new memory for the next input)
        offset = 0;
        size = read_size;
        free(buff);
        buff = NULL;
        buff = malloc(size + 1);
        *buff = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        offset += res;
        buff[offset] = '\0';
        
        if (offset + read_size > size)
        {
            size *= 2;
            buff = realloc(buff, size+1);
        }
    }
}
```

If this isn't possible with read() I can try with something else like fgets() perhaps?

Comment: using read is very rare, its slow and un helpful, use fgets

Comment: @pm100 `read()` is slow?!?!?!?

Comment: You cannot compare a string using `==`... you must use `strcmp`

Comment: And `read` is best when reading binary data. `fgets` is more appropriate for text. Then use `sscanf` to parse the text.

Comment: @SGeorgiades how would strcmp() work for the second input with "p N" since the number N could be any number? I thought about using strstr() but it still would have issues. For example when inputting "ghdje" the program will exit because the string contains "e".

Comment: @AndrewHenle It depends on how `read` is used: Under Linux, `fgets` calls `read`, so `fgets` cannot be faster than `read`. However, if you read the input byte-by-byte by calling `read` (for each byte), this will be much slower than calling `fgets` that calls `read` only once in the best case.

Comment: After `char *buff = malloc(size+1);`, it is guaranteed that `buff != "p"`.  That is not how you compare strings.  Perhaps you meant `buff[0] == 'p'`

Comment: @Deutrys If you use `fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin)` followed by `cnt = sscanf(line," %c %d",&cmd,&num);`, then you can just compare `cmd` against 'e' and 'p', and for 'p', confirm that `cnt == 2` and use the value of `num`. I will post a full answer below.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if(buff == "p")
> ```

This line checks if the string `buff` is stored at the same address as the string `"p"`. However, you don't want to check if the strings are stored at the same address, but if they have the same content.

> ... how would strcmp() work ...

Using `strcmp()` you can check if two strings are identical:

```
if(!strcmp(buff, "e"))
```

> "p N" ... since the number N could be any number?

Simply check if the first character of `buff` is `'p'`:

```
if(buff[0] == 'p')
```

Note that single quotes (`'`) are used instead of double quotes (`"`) for character constants (in contrast to string constants).

Comment: Yeah this would work, but only for the "e" case. An input like "psadgjuinsad" would also go into "if(buff[0] == 'p')". And also how am I going to get the value of N?

Answer (score 0):

As I described in my comment above, here is a full answer:

```
int main(void)
{
    char line[100], cmd;
    int num, cnt;

    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin)) != EOF) {       
        cnt = sscanf(line," %c %d",&cmd,&num);
        if (cnt == 0) {
            // empty line, no command
        } else if (cmd == 'e') {
            // exit the program
            break;
        } else if (cmd == 'p'  &&  cnt == 2) {
            // no something with num
        } else {
            // print a message
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```